# PHP:: mySQLi Create a new table (if not exists) from existed sql file

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mysqli, server

Is it possible to create a table (if not exists) from existed sql file?

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {FROM FILE : myFile.SQL}";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: `$sql = file_get_contents('file.sql'); mysqli_query($con, $sql);`, basically, though this most likely won't work as is.

Comment: So Simple ;) I'll give it a try!